# SQLite - Why import with "UNIQUE constraint failed" is slow?

Tags: command-line, import, sqlite, database-performance

I have a CSV file `test.csv` with **a lot** of unique records of type `(text,int,int)`, where the text field is no more than 70 characters.

When executing the following statements the speed is usually around 80 MiB/s:

```
sqlite3 db 'create table test(a text,b int,c int,primary key(a,b,c) without rowid'
pv test.csv | sqlite3 -init <(echo -e '.mode csv\n.import /dev/stdin test') db
```

But when executing the following statement again the speed is usually under 100 KiB/s and a lot of `UNIQUE constraint failed` are printed to stderr:

```
pv test.csv | sqlite3 -init <(echo -e '.mode csv\n.import /dev/stdin test') db
```

It seems to me that in both cases SQLite needs to check for the same constraint, so how come the case where nothing is written to disk is **much much** slower than the case where everything is written to disk?

And the most important question - how can I make the secondary import faster? This database needs to be updated daily, and the records are mostly new, but some of them already exists in the database. This makes the import to slow to process.

BTW this is the same case with SSD and HHD, though SSD is a bit faster.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you redirect standard output and error to /dev/null?

Comment: @Shawn Yeah I already tried this. Also very slow.